# Would a Jabari ruler of Wakanda take on the mantle of Black Panther?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018, black-panther

If a Jabari challenger for the Wakandan crown had won in the ritual combat and been made ruler, would they still receive visions  and power of the panther goddess Bast, or from their own Gorilla deity, and a different suit matching that theme? Answers from any canon would work, since this scenario is not seen in the MCU

Comment: The Black Gorilla would be awesome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on Earth 616 (the main Marvel comics continuity).

It is apparently the 'Heart-Shaped Herb' that is said to link the Black Panther to the Panther goddess Bast [Black Panther Vol 4 Issue 2], although there is apparently a scientific reason for the increased strength and senses that the herb gives involving a mutation of the plant from Vibranium [Black Panther Vol 3 Issue 1].

Anyone who uses this herb who is "not worthy or of noble blood" would perish according to Wakandan folklore [Fantastic Four Vol 1 Issue 52].

This is partially backed up by the attempt of Klaw to use the herb, who almost perished in the attempt [mentioned in Black Panther Vol 3 61].

So to actually answer your question (if this scenario took place on Earth 616), the Jabari challenger wouldn't actually gain the powers of Bast (via the Heart-Shaped Herb), instead it would make them very ill or possibly kill them (unless they had close blood ties to the royal family, which I can't find any reference of).

Comment: So they’re allowed to challenge for the throne, win the title of black panther, but then they die?

Comment: I would imagine that after 2000+ years of isolation, everyone would be massively inbred and they'd all have "Royal Blood"

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo In Avengers Vol 1 Issue 62, a member of the Jabari village (Man-Ape) drugged and beat the Black Panther in combat (he still had to sucker punch him to beat him). The Jabari victor didn't use the Heart-Shaped Herb, although he already had increased strength from consuming the flesh of a white gorilla. Worth noting that he wanted Wakanda to worship the White Gorilla god instead of Bast, so probably didn't want to be linked to Bast through the ceremony involving the Heart-Shaped Herb.

Comment: Apparently the royal family didn't take this into account when they offered the Heart Shaped Herb to the Jabari in the movie.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus - A very valid point. As stated on the first line of my answer, I applied the question to the comics continuity (as the question allows for such), but it is quite possible that it is not applicable to the MCU continuity.

Comment: I’m going to have to probably accept your answer even if it’s not what I was after/the one I wanted. The MCU makes it seem as though any of the other tribes are of royal blood and could possibly become king - the comics seem... well, not so much

Comment: Your conclusion and answer to the question must be incorrect; if a Jabari were to win the contest to become ruler of Wakanda then surely they would be "worthy".

Comment: I’m guessing here - but it would seem in 616 continuity the Jabari ARE NOT valid royal blood/able to challenge for the throne like in the movies. My question ends up having a schizophrenic answer because I know damn well the Marvel Film Black Panther doesn’t show what I’m asking